# arduino: loop until int gets value assigned to it

Tags: while-loop, arduino, serial-port, arduino-uno

I am trying to get a value from serial input. The rest of the programm behaves different if the value changes. This value gest assigned once in the ```void setup()``` function.
My goal is to let the program run an infinite loop or something similar until a value (type int) is recived, and only then resume the flow. 
I know about ```Serial.parseInt()``` and tried to implement it ``` while (variable == null) variable = Serial.parseInt() ``` but I got an error that 'null' was not declared in this scope.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oke, i was kinda dumb.
There is an easy way, simply check

```
while (!variable) 
  variable = Serial.parseInt()
```

This worked for me and should work for you as well